# Для чего можно использовать сочетание клавиш Ctrl+Shift+B в PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

В PyCharm есть сочетание клавиш Ctrl+Shift+B c описанием

> Navigate to a type declaration of a symbol at caret, the symbol being
>   a variable or a method call.

Что-то не могу разобраться, как увидеть, что данная комбинация работает и для чего вообще она. Ведь в питоне вроде как нет декларации типа переменной.

Comment: у самой переменной типа нет, а у ее содержимого - есть, и, если IDE можно однозначно определить тип (e.g. `x = dict()`), то получает возможность использовать все возвможности, получаемый за счет знания типа

Comment: А скинь ,пожалуйста, если не тяжело, пример кода, что бы можно было наблюдать это.

Comment: я даже не питонщик, но если подключите .pyi, то сможете увидеть сами